# How to run a PHP chat program in a free cPanel host?

Tags: php, sockets, client-server, chat, shared-hosting

I have created a client server chat application in PHP. It uses socket programming to communicate. It works fine on my Fedora using terminal. But I need to host the chat in a server. But I don't own any server, so I use free hosting site (with cPanel).

Is there any way to run the socket programmed chat server on a free web server without access to its terminal?

Comment: How does the script listen - does it run constantly in the background? If so, that is unlikely to be permitted to run on a free host. I am not sure if they will allow arbitrary socket listeners either, since a listener will take up a whole port per IP. I think you might need a VPS (though with limited detail to go on, it's hard to say).

Comment: Is it possible to send a TCP/UDP message from a free host server to my PC? Do they allow sending such packets on a Http Request?

Comment: Would you edit the code you are using to do that, into your question?

Comment: I'm just self researching on these stuffs. I would write a new code for that. :) 
Do u know any way i can send a encrypted message to a local host(eg: my local pc) from a free hosting server???

Comment: It depends on the host, but in general the answer is no. As Antony says, get a cheap VPS - it saves the hassle of having to work around these restrictions.

Comment: But i'm not gonna get a VPS for such small thing, i'm sure i can work around. I already got the half way there. All I need is a response from the server! hmm... Anyway thank you for the comments. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just made my local machine, a server by port forwarding the modem and incorporated dynamic-dns technique to follow up the user's IP Addresses and finally, created a peer-to-peer connection between users to enable chat.

Problem solved without using a free hosting site!!!

Comment: That'll work, but your home bandwidth is limited and the latency won't be great. Also, home computers generally have more downtime than rack-based servers, even if you intend to keep them on 24/7.

Comment: Your are right. But, it works well for my testing and private communication.

Answer (score 2):

Most free hosts don't allow php modules like socket, curl.

Also many of them forbid using functions like file_get_contents and fopen when you want to fetch some url by http - actually it's still using sockets.

Plus, if we talk about chat server, you need to listen to connections on some specific port, and custom inbound connections are even more likely to be forbidden.

One reason for such security features is not to allow people utilize free hosting network resources, setting up different scrapers, spam-posters, etc.

Better get yourself some cheap VPS, because even paid virtual hosting plans are often limited to same rules as stated above.

Answer (score 1):

If you don't have access to any external server resources, you could use a polling technique instead. Socket.IO has functionality to fall back to use XMLHttpRequest polling if no method of connection is possible through websockets, or using flash.

For example, on the client, you can set the option:

```
io.set('polling duration', 5);
```

This will cause Socket.IO to perform an AJAX request every 5 seconds internally. On the server side, you will need to use something like [elephant.io](http://elephant.io/). Unfortunately, there don't seem to be many alternatives without having to roll your own server-side solution.

Because the PHP script won't be constantly running on the back-end, you'll need to design some mechanism to keep track of user state. This can be rather complicated, but if you're only doing this for learning purposes, you could store it in a user session in a database, or on the client-side. Whenever a request is made from the client, you would then query your database to retrieve the user session, then go from there using Socket.IO methodologies.

Comment: Is it possible to send a TCP/UDP message from a free host server to my PC? Do they allow sending such packets on a Http Request?